# XPath square bracket operator produces unexpected result

Tags: xpath, xslt

Consider this XML document:

```xml
<foo>
    <bar id="aaa"/>
    <jam>
        <bar id="bbb"/>
    </jam>
</foo>
```

I am trying to find the first `<bar>` element in the document.

Here's what I've discovered:

| Test# | XPath Expression | Evaluation Expression | Result |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | `//bar` | `@id` | `aaa`, `bbb` |
| 2 | `//bar[1]` | `@id` | `aaa`, `bbb` |
| 3 | `(//bar)[1]` | `@id` | `aaa` |

What I don't understand is why Test #2 returns `aaa`, `bbb` instead of just `aaa`. It's as if the `[1]` operator is not working.

My understanding was that in Test #2, the `//bar` expression would find both nodes, and then the `[1]` operator would choose the first one. Obviously, I'm missing something.

This seems to be confirmed by Test #3 which is apparently how to express what I really want.

Also, if you change the XML document to this:

```xml
<foo>
    <bar id="aaa"/>
    <bar id="bbb"/>
</foo>
```

then you get what I was expecting to see:

| Test# | XPath Expression | Evaluation Expression | Result |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | `//bar` | `@id` | `aaa`, `bbb` |
| 2 | `//bar[1]` | `@id` | `aaa` |
| 3 | `(//bar)[1]` | `@id` | `aaa` |

What subtlety am I missing here about how `[1]` is supposed to work?

Comment: In all your questions regarding XSLT, please state which version of XSLT your processor supports.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The XPath specification contains this note regarding the `//` abbreviated syntax:

> **Note**:
> The path expression `//para[1`] does not mean the same as the path expression `/descendant::para[1]`. The latter selects the first descendant `para` element; the former selects all descendant `para` elements that are the first `para` children of their respective parents.

IOW, if you want to select the first `bar` element in the document you need to use:

```
/descendant::bar[1]
```

instead of:

```
//bar[1]
```

---

Unlike the other answers, I am not claiming it makes sense.

Answer (score 3):

> What subtlety am I missing here about how [1] is supposed to work?

In `//bar[1]`, the predicate `[1]` is attached to the step `child::bar` and evaluated in the context of that step.  The predicate therefore asks whether the node in question is *the first child of its parent*, not whether it is the first of all the nodes that would be selected by `//bar`.  The latter is what `(//bar)[1]` means.